# How to call User Control's Method from another User Control?

Tags: vb.net

I can't call the method of my another user control from one user control. Nothing happens.
Say I have a control1 and control2 names of my controls.

In control1 I have a method InvokeItems() which is to populate my DataGridView in control1.
In control2 I have a button that will call InvokeItems() method in control1.

control1 and control2 are both loaded at the same time in a form.
control1 loads correctly the data in my DataGridView however when I updated the data in my database and click the button in control1 to load again the details nothing happens.

I wanted to call the method in control1 to check for any updates in recordset. That should be supposedly I wanted to happen. But I could not get it working.

But when I put a button in control2 and call the InvokeItems method it loads correcty the DataGridView even if I updated some data in my database.

Here's what I did.

In control1:

```
Public Sub New()
    InvokeItems()
End Sub

Public Sub InvokeItems()

    Dim objInvoker As New ClassItems
    Dim BS As New BindingSource()

    BS.DataSource = objInvoker.InvokeList
    GridItems.DataSource = BS

End Function
```

In control2:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objSM As New control1
    Call objSM.InvokeItems()
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions..

Comment: How do you bind a button to call Populate?

Comment: @norekhov I forgot to mention I have a class named ClassItems which has method InvokeList to populate my grid. P.S.I have updated my questions above.

Answer (score 0):

The handler on your Control2 creates a new instance of Control1, this is not the instance that your grid is on.

You could create a property on Control2 and pass in a Control1 instance after it is constructed.

Or simply handle this event in a scope that has access to both controls i.e the Form they are located.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll work it on.. and give you feedback of the outcome.